# textfield opens keyboard flutter scaffold

Tags: flutter, text, scaffolding

As you can see from the [video I posted](https://file.io/bLvWfANHre9z), I have a constraint problem regarding the textfield below. once I press, the keyboard opens but it overlaps and ruins the whole view. how can I solve and manage the problem?

The problem perhaps is that the dimensions for the qrima are badly set.

they advised me to manage everything in a Scaffold and then set resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false but I don't notice any improvements

I have already asked this question, and they told me to enclose everything in a scaffold. I tried but this really ruins the view, I don't see anything

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    _buttonHeight = size.height * .05;

    double splitPoint = size.height / 7;

    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Stack(
            children: [FutureBuilder<UserData>(
          future: contentManager.getUserData(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<UserData> snapUserData) {
            if (snapUserData.hasError)
              return Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("There was some error"),
                ),
              );
            if (snapUserData.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
              return Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(appColors.yellow)),
                ),
              );
            return Stack(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
              children: [
                // SFONDO
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: size.height,
                    width: size.width,
                    color: appColors.primaryColor,
                  ),
                ),
                // TITOLO
                Positioned(
                  top: size.height * .05,
                  child: Text(
                    localization.showQR,
                    style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                      color: appColors.green,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: size.height * .10,
                  width: size.width * .8,
                  child: qrCodeHolder,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: size.height * .18,
                  width: size.width * .8,
                  child: AutoSizeText(
                    localization.home_subLabel,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                      color: appColors.green,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: size.height * .08,
                  width: size.width * .7,
                  height: size.height * .05,
                  child: TextField(
                    inputFormatters: [
                      new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(11),
                    ],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      //height: 2.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    ]),
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have to say you are using stack and positioned too much. There is no need to calculate everything. Rather use flutter widgets like Expanded or padding to make required space between and around widgets. I could not easily fix your code but I at least tried to write it in similar way. This code will prevent input overlay. Please check:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {

  final Future<String> getUserData = Future<String>.delayed(
    const Duration(seconds: 2),
    () => 'Data Loaded',
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder<String>(
                    future: getUserData,
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapUserData) {
                      if (snapUserData.hasError)
                        return Container(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("There was some error"),
                          ),
                        );
                      if (snapUserData.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
                        return Container(
                          child: Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                    Colors.yellow)),
                          ),
                        );
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          // TITOLO
                          Text(
                            "qr",
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .primaryTextTheme
                                .headline5
                                .copyWith(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                          ),

                          Expanded(
                              child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                            "something",
                          ))),
                          Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                              child: TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                  //height: 2.0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: error: a build function returned null. HomeTab. "Container()" to return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room,

Comment: some idea ?i tried to remove the padding but same error

Comment: well, thats not enough info about the error. Whats HomeTab? It seem it comes from different place in the app. If you call the TestPage as material page route it works. Like this: "onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TestPage()),
  );
}". More info here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Comment: no sorry I was wrong, now the problem is another. the view is correct, I just have to correct:
- I have to slightly lower the textfield, now it puts it too attached at the top
- when he opens the keyboard, he tells me: Bottom overflowed by 143 pixels

Comment: I think I understand that the size does not work well when opening the keyboard

Comment: I updated the post by adding the image. in practice I have to add a side button to the textfiel and then solve the problem again if I raise the keyboard